# Не получается заменить TextView по нажатию кнопки

Tags: java, android, исключения

Хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки на экране вывелась разметка файла **razm2.xml**, и в этой разметке у меня есть `TextView`, и так же после нажатия кнопки текст в этом `TextView` менялся на мой.

Делаю так:

```
TextView messLenin;
Button buttonLenin;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.linin);


    messLenin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messLenin);

    Button buttonLenin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLenin);
    buttonLenin.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonLenin:
            setContentView(R.layout.razm2);
            messLenin.setText("Мой текст");
        break;
     }
}
```

Но получаю вылет из приложения после нажатия кнопки:

> 09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at ru.mail.xaxa.Lenin.onClick(Lenin.java:54)
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   09-27 14:43:10.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

А если убрать замену текста в `TextView ( messLenin.setText("Мой текст"); )` после нажатия кнопки то все нормально, разметка меняется..

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Вот хорошо оформленный вопрос. С кратким листингом, чётким описанием желаемого поведения, примером попыток сделать как надо и логами ошибки. +1

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо.

Comment: Подмена разметки активити - очень плохая практика, которая заведет вас в большие и трудно решаемые проблемы в дальнейшем, когда на активити будет больше одного виджета. Виджеты с одинаковыми именами на разных разметках еще большее зло, чем первое. Ваша логика абсолютно не применима на практике.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в строке

```
setContentView(R.layout.razm2);
```

меняется главная `ContentView` и там уже нету `R.id.messLenin` или есть но в другом адресе. Так что попробуйте добавить это

```
setContentView(R.layout.razm2);
messLenin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messLenin);
messLenin.setText("Мой текст");
```

Comment: Я бы не советовал поощрять решениями настолько структурно-неверные подходы. Сама логика абсолютно нежизнеспособна в реальной практике